# WPF: How to Bind data from a List to ComboBox inside a Treeview Node

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm trying to bind data that is inside **UserLevelCategories** list to a ComboBox inside a Treeview.
The **UserLevelCategories **list is inside another list - **systemBranches**.

Model:

```
public class SystemBranchViewModel
{
    public int LocalSystemId { get; set; }
    public string LocalSystemName { get; set; }
    public List<BranchModel> Branches { get; set; }
    public List<UserLevelCategoryModel> UserLevelCategories { get; set; }
}
```

Code Behind:

```
List<SystemBranchViewModel> systemBranches = new List<SystemBranchViewModel>();
systemBranches = getDataService.GetSystemBranchesByUser();
Branch_List.ItemsSource = systemBranches;
```

XAML:

```
<TreeView Name="Branch_List">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type branch:SystemBranchViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Branches}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LocalSystemName}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type branch:BranchModel}">
            <WrapPanel>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsBranchActiveToUser}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding BranchName }" />
            </WrapPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type branch:UserLevelCategoryModel}">
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding UserLevelCategories}"
                      DisplayMemberPath="{Binding UserLevelCategoryName}"
                      SelectedValuePath="{Binding UserLevelCategoryId}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Output should look like this:

1. System A

   - BranchName 1
   - BranchName 2
   - Permission: ComboBox
     -UserLevelCategoryName 1
     -UserLevelCategoryName 2
2. System B

   - BranchName 1
   - BranchName 2
   - Permission: ComboBox
     -UserLevelCategoryName 1
     -UserLevelCategoryName 2

Answer (score 0):

If you put the `ComboBox` in the template for `BranchModel`, you could bind to the `UserLevelCategories` property of the parent of the parent's `DataContext` like this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.UserLevelCategories, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeViewItem, AncestorLevel=2}}" ... />
```

You won't need a separate template for the `UserLevelCategoryModel` type.